# Velocity from acceleration data

Tags: matlab

I have measured acceleration data from accelerometers. I want to get the velocity from the data by integrating it using MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
%clear
clc;

%Create a baseline sinusoidal signal
ch1_100mss = ch1_100ms xdata = ch1_100mss; y0 = sin(xdata);

%Add noise to the signal
noise = 2*y0.*randn(size(y0)); % Response-dependent
ydata = y0 + noise; % Gaussian noise

%Fit the noisy data with a custom sinusoidal model
f = fittype('a*sin(b*x)'); fit1 = fit(xdata,ydata,f,'StartPoint',[1 1]);

%Find the integral of the fit at the predictors
int = integrate(fit1,xdata,0);

%Plot the data, the fit, and the integral
subplot(2,1,1) plot(fit1,xdata,ydata) % cfit plot method subplot(2,1,2) plot(xdata,int,'m') % double plot method grid on legend('integral') plot(fit1,xdata,ydata,{'fit','integral'})
```

When I run the code, the warning below appears

```
Warning: Minimum step size reached; singularity possible.
> In quad at 103
  In cfit.integrate at 42
  In integration at 23

Warning: Minimum step size reached; singularity possible.
> In quad at 103
  In cfit.integrate at 40
  In cfit.plot at 138
  In integration at 33

Warning: Minimum step size reached; singularity possible.
> In quad at 103
  In cfit.integrate at 42
  In cfit.plot at 138
  In integration at 33
```

Is my result valid anyways?

Comment: You may wish to add a matlab tag here. I might know integration, but not Matlab's API.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the fitted data looks as it should?

Comment: Since your code does not generate a sample signal I used `xdata = linspace(0,20*pi,1000).';`. With that your algorithm works fine and integrate with no warning. The problem comes from your original signal. As Patrick mentioned, double check your original data and your fit _before_ you try to integrate.

Comment: Ok. the mathworks forum help me to understand the singularity.

Comment: the plotted data not so convincing

Comment: Because i want to integrate my own signal which from experimental work. So, the xdata= ch1_100mss.  How to check my original signal and what to check? is it because the data is in negative integer?